# IQkeyboardmanager Toolbar Done Button Off Screen

Tags: objective-c, iqkeyboardmanager

I'm trying to clean up an existing project. It uses `IQKeyboardManager`.

The buttons in the toolbar of the Keyboard manager are drifting off screen.

Do you know where and how I might set the constraint for this? thanks!

Notice how the Done button is leaving the screen to the right:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You are probably using version older than v5.0.10. Please use latest version, this issue has been fixed already.

Comment: Updating to a newer version solved this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Updating to a newer version of IQKeyBoardManager solved this issue.